# Rails Facebook like and share buttons only show when page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have just added the Facebook like/share button from the developers site. For some reason the buttons will not show up on any page unless you reload the page. here is what I have for the Javascript

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and here is the div for the actual like/share button

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://localhost:3000/parts" data-layout="button_count"data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Is there anything here I need to change from the development site to make the buttons appear without having to reload the page? Thank you for the help.

UPDATE

My Turbolinks is disabled which could be affecting this. Is there a way to get this to work without turbo links?

UPDATE

In case if it helps my javascript and button div are both in the `<body>` tags while the link preview is in the `<head>`

```
<head>
    <!-- You can use open graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
    <meta property="og:url"           content="http://http://localhost:3000/parts" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="JMR" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Garage" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <h4><%= part.name %></small></h4>
      <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-width="50" data-layout="standard"
       data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you using Turbolinks?

Comment: i have them disabled. Do I need to have them enabled for this to work? Is there a way I can leave turbo links disabled and to have it still work?

Comment: Nah. Disabled is better. Turbolinks can interfere with how the SDK loads.

Comment: yes I agree...but is there a way to get this to work without turbo links?

Comment: Where is your javascript? In the head? body?

Comment: @Anand i made an opening and closing body take and put it in between there on the page I wanted the like button to be on. Should the Javascript be in the application view?